# 400 bad request from next/image

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, nextjs-image

So I am trying to display images with next/image's  component. However, the images are not being displayed. I believe this is because of a 400 bad request error next/image is giving me.

[image]

When I click on that URL, it says "The requested resource isn't a valid image" which is strange because after retrieving the image url from the backend, I AM able to download the image to see that it is a valid image, so this error is happening right after the image link is passed in the props of the  component. Basically, my requests are correct, but next/image's interaction with the image url is being messed up. What's weird is that I also did not have this error a few days ago, and after not changing anything, I'm seeing this error.

I've configured the next.js config file like this, and the request to the backend does retrieve a downloadable image (next/image is just not displaying it correctly).

Here is my config file for next.js:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withImages = require('next-images');

const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: [
      'url.s3.amazonaws.com',
      'url.s3.amazonaws.com',
      'url.s3.amazonaws.com',
    ],
  },
  
};


module.exports = withPlugins([[withImages]], nextConfig);
```

Comment: I get this problem after updating next from 10.0.8 to 11. On 10 version all works fine

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with next 12. Running fine on local build but no images when deployed on Netlify

Answer (score 6):

I'm late for the topic, but hope my answer will help someone else.

Adding the domain's config into the next.config.js is not enough (only work for local):

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  images: {
    domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com'],
  }
}
```

For production, you need to make sure that your "next" instance grabs that config.

So in my case, what I did to make it work is:

Before

```
const nextjsDistDir = join("src", require("./src/next.config.js").distDir);
const nextjsServer = next({
  dev: isDev,
  conf: {
    distDir: nextjsDistDir
  }
});
```

After

```
const nextjsDistDir = join("src", require("./src/next.config.js").distDir);
const nextjsServer = next({
  dev: isDev,
  conf: {
    distDir: nextjsDistDir,
    images: {
      domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com'],
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Which file are these changes in?

Comment: @RobSutcliffe ----->  server.js

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this issue happened only with the docker container.
It turns out the issue was the `Dockerfile` that did not copy also the `next.config.js` file where I configured the image optimizations.

Basically, it was missing this line:

```
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
```

this is the `Dockerfile` that I use:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY public ./public
RUN  npm install --production

FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV NODE_ENV production

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If this helped you, please remember to vote and select the as correct answer

Comment: I am using docker and this did it. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I wouldn't have caught this easily. Thanks, a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Using loader function solves the issue. Don't know why. But updating the version is the best option.

```
<Image
    loader={()=>user.coverImage}
      src={user.coverImage}
      alt="user cover image"
      layout="fill"
      objectFit="cover"
/>
```

Comment: Hi, @Shiroshan; Could you show us the reference of coverImage funtion?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to next.js version 11. The issue has been fixed with the [next@11.0.2-canary.4](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v11.0.2-canary.4) version. You can update the version. The problem will be solved.

Comment: I have the same issue and tried this (even later version than suggested as well) and still have the same issue.

Comment: Are you currently using the latest version? @Spirconi

Comment: Yes, i tried next@11.0.2-canary.4 as suggested and now on 11.1.3-canary.52 just to try. Unfortunately same issue. I am thinking it s something AWS side. But then, it works fine on local.

Comment: I don't have information exactly. I am currently using 11.0.2-canary.22. I am not having any problems. I've never had this problem since -canary.4. You can try 11.0.2-canary.22.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. You are using AWS right? Will try 22 now.

Comment: Yes i using AWS. Good luck :)

Comment: No luck im afraid

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your nextjs version ?
it seems 10.1.X and newer have some problems...
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/23523

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a domain name including `www` prefix into `next.config.js`. E.g. both `googlapis.com` and `www.googleapis.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the image first.

```
import product_1 from '../public/src/assets/images/ecommerce/product_img_01.jpg'
```

and then imported

```
import Image from 'next/image'
```

and used it as so.

```
<Image src={product_1} />
```

and everything worked fine in next version 12.3.1

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `.env` file put this code :

```
STRAPI_ASSETS_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:1337 // your strapi domain
```

2. Go to that page where your image component and put this code :

```js
const { STRAPI_ASSETS_BASE_URL } = process.env;
```

3. Add `STRAPI_ASSETS_BASE_URL` in `<Image src={}/>`

```js
<Image src={STRAPI_ASSETS_BASE_URL + p.thumbnail.data.attributes.url} height={500} width={500} alt="product-img"/>
```

4. In `next.config.js` file put below code:

```js
images: {
     domains: ["127.0.0.1"],
},
```

It will 100% work.

[image: step:1]
[image: step:2 & 3]
[image: step:4]

Answer (score -3):

Run in console at proyect route: `rm -rf .next/`

Then run the server again and try

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).