# next/image images not loading on iis 10 server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iis, next.js

I published my nextjs application with iisnode on iis 10 server, everything works smoothly, but the local images I use next/image are not loaded. In the development environment, next dev, next build, next start etc. It works smoothly with commands. the problem occurs only when I run it on the iis server.

I list below the information I got while trying to solve the problem.

- There is no problem with the images I source from a different url.
- There is no problem with the images I use `<img>` tag
- If I go to the url in the form _next/url=..., the image opens fine
- If I open cmd on the server and do npm run start and enter the site and load the images, the cache folder in the .next folder is filled with images and when I enter the site from the normal url again, the images come back.
- I have tried many methods without success and I also use cloudflare.

The information is this way code etc. I don't think there is a problem in the part, if I need extra information, I will provide it. I will be glad if you can help.

Edit: It doesn't seem to be a problem with path. Because the src that the application gives me is "https://******.com/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fhero.webp&w=1920&q=75" so when I go to this link I get the error ""url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid" but if I try with the url "https://******.com/%2Fimages%2Fhero.webp" I can see the image actually. I don't know exactly which part of the code I should share, everything looks healthy locally. And this is the only debug I can get

Fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060446/18792939

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with path. Because the src that the application gives me is "https://******.com/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fhero.webp&w=1920&q=75" so when I go to this link I get the error ""url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid" but if I try with the url "https://******.com/%2Fimages%2Fhero.webp" I can see the image actually.

I don't know exactly which part of the code I should share, everything looks healthy locally. And this is the only debug I can get

Answer (score 0):

Need to make some changes in your next.config.js file

need to write your domain in the next.config.js file

like

```
images: {
domains: [
  "example.com",
],
```

Comment: I have already done this, there is no problem with the images connected to domain, the problem is with the local images

Comment: you have added and image uploaded on server are the same.
because I have faced the same issue.

Comment: suppose 
<Image
                  src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/8b/16/7a/8b167af653c2399dd93b952a48740620.jpg"
                  alt={`Profile of ${user.name}`}
                  className={styles.userImage}
                  width={100}
                  height={100}
                />
this is user image then you to add domain in next.config.js is 
images: {
    domains: [
      "i.pinimg.com",
    ],
  },